# Terraform 0.11.1 does not support state version 4

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

1mError loading state: Terraform 0.11.1 does not support state version 4, please update .  how can i resolve this error in terraform

Comment: Use a more recent version of Terraform. In reality you should be using the same version of Terraform that wrote your state file.

Comment: Terraform 0.11.1 was released in October 2018, the current (Jan 2020) release is 0.12.18. The 0.12 release is a major version upgrade so you should check the upgrade process and checklist here before upgrading: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html

Answer (score 2):

Terraform does not support state version 4 is a common issue.

There is only one fix to this

1. Take the local state file and push it to some remote backend and then delete the .terraform directory and run the init command with the backend.

It should work

Comment: This is not working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually arises when state file gets corrupt. If your state file is being stored in a remote s3 backend and if the bucket has versioning enabled then you might want to delete the latest state file and revert back to older state file and make your changes again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when i specified a local backend configuration, like this:

```html
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "./.terraform/terraform.tfstate"
  }
```

Removed that and it worked just fine. Had to recreate the state tho